# Unable to understand overloading of assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, constants

To understand the working of objects in c++ better, I wrote this piece of code:

```
using namespace std;

char n[] = "\n";

class T
{
  private:
    int num;

  public:
    T ()
    {
        num = 0;
        cout << n << (long)this % 0xFF << " created without param";
    }

    T (const int param)
    {
        num = param;
        cout << n << (long)this % 0xFF << " created with param = " << param;
    }

    T (const T& obj)
    {
        num = obj.num;
        cout << n << (long)this % 0xFF << " created as copy of " << (long)&obj % 0xFF;
    }

    const T& operator= (const T& obj)
    {
        if (this == &obj)
            return *this;
        num = obj.num;
        cout << n << (long)this % 0xFF << " got assigned the data of " << (long)&obj % 0xFF;
        return *this;
    }

    ~T ()
    {
        cout << n << (long)this % 0xFF << " destroyed";
    }

    int get () const {return num;}
    void set (const int param) {num = param;}
};

T PlusTen (T obj)
{
    T newObj(5);
    newObj.set( obj.get() +10 );
    return newObj;
}

int main ()
{
    T a, b(4);
    a = b;
    a = PlusTen(b);

    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Its working fine, but when I remove the `const` qualifier in "return-type" and "parameter" of overloaded assignment operator like this below:

```
T& operator= (T& obj) // const removed
{
    if (this == &obj)
        return *this;
    num = obj.num;
    cout << n << (long)this % 0xFF << " got assigned the data of " << (long)&obj % 0xFF;
    return *this;
}
```

Then this line of main function gives error:

```
a = PlusTen(b);
```

The error message being:

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'T' and 'T')
    note:
    candidate is: T& T::operator=(T&)
    no known conversion for argument 1 from 'T' to 'T&'
```

**If operand types of 'T' and 'T' are problematic, how come the line just above it (`a = b;`) is totally fine? They too are of operand types 'T' and 'T' !!**

---

I found a relevant questoin here but no useful detail there:
[why must you provide the keyword const in operator overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949976/why-must-you-provide-the-keyword-const-in-operator-overloads)
One person there says that if we don't use `const` in operator=, we can only use it for `non-const` objects. But in my case too both sides are non-const. Then why error? Especially when the line just above it, which is identical in operand types, compiles fine?

---

Compiler used: MinGW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
T PlusTen (T obj)
{
    T newObj(5);
    newObj.set( obj.get() +10 );
    return newObj;
}
```

returns a temporary object of type `T`. this temporary object can be bound with a constant reference.

> This is important! This is the reason OP is confused!
> Non-const references to temporary objects are not allowed in C++ !! In case of `a = PlusTen(b);`, as `PlusTen(b)` is a temporary value, the function `operator=` cannot bind the argument `obj` to `PlusTen(b)` value, because `obj` is non-const whereas `PlusTen(b)` can only be const.

So the compiler issues an error because the parameter of the assignment operator

```
T& operator= (T& obj)
              ^^^^^^
```

is not a constant reference.

The qualifier `const` in the return type makes no matter in the context how the operator is used in your program.

Answer (score 3):

`PlusTen(b);` is creating a temporary object. Since non-const references can not be bound to temporary objects, `operator=` can not be called here.

In `a = b;` `b` is not a temporary, it's a modifiable object (a so-called *l-value*). Non-const reference is successfully bound to it, and `operator=` is called.

For the extra fun, try defining your `b` as following:

```
const T b(4);
```